# login issue . I am using php version 7.2

Tags: php

I am using PHP  7.2 version Login issue. I want to make a session directly after the success Login goes to the index page. But always redirectly Login Page. working fine PHP 5.6 version but only issue php 7.2 version please check it's and share the idea.

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
require 'setting/config.php';
error_reporting(0);
$username  =  $_POST['username'];
$password  =  $_POST['password'];
$login     =  $_POST['login'];
if(isset($login)){
  $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM login where username='$username' and password='$password'");
  $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
  $name = $row['name_login'];
  $user = $row['username'];
  $pass = $row['password'];
  $type = $row['type_login'];
  if($user==$username && $pass=$password){

    if($type=="admin"){ 
        $_SESSION['mysesi']=$name;
        $_SESSION['mytype']=$type;
        session_regenerate_id(false);
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";

    } else if($type=="user"){
        $_SESSION['mysesi']=$name;
        $_SESSION['mytype']=$type;
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";

    } else if($type=="super"){
        $_SESSION['mysesi']=$name;
        $_SESSION['mytype']=$type;
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('super.php')</script>";

    } else{
        $msg="your Login successfully !";
    }
  } else{
    $msg=" worng please try again!";
  }
}
?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'setting/config.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['mysesi']) && !isset($_SESSION['mytype'])=='admin')
{
  echo "<script>window.location.assign('sign-in.php')</script>";
}
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "proyello_db");
  if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: You appear to be using Plain Text Password. That is very bad. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: how to make security and working fine 7.2 ves.

Comment: yes now using md5 ok sir but ?

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1().

Comment: Not sure why you show us `session.php` you dont seem to use it in the `login.php` code

Comment: then what useing?

Comment: i was understand but my issue is a login problem only working php 5.6 but i need workin on 7.2 ?

Comment: this code is not working sir ?

Comment: Also, it would be much better and simpler to use `header('Location: xxx.php');` instead of little blocks of javascript to move to another page

Comment: _“but i need workin on 7.2”_ - no, no one needs a script written this poorly to work under any PHP version. This is _dangerous_. Use a login solution from an established framework or something - you clearly lack the skills necessary to implement your own properly at this point. (I’d go so far as to say until you are able to debug issues like this on your own, you should not be writing any such functionality yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this part:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'setting/config.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['mysesi']) && !isset($_SESSION['mytype'])=='admin')
{
  echo "<script>window.location.assign('sign-in.php')</script>";
}
?>
```

You are including session.php in every page, right?
What it does is checking if `$_SESSION['myesi']` is set (true after login) and if `$_SESSION['mytype'] === 'admin'`.

The issue is that `mytype` index of `$_SESSION` is only admin if you login as admin. As a normal user or "super" the body of the if will be executed forwarding you to `sign-in.php`. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: absulatly sir ?

Comment: What do you mean @Pankaj?

Comment: Except the `login.php` does not appear to actually include `session.php`

Comment: Yes, but login.php redirects to index.php and in index.php session.php seems to be included -> redirects back to sign-in.php. @Pankaj could track this by opening the browser's network console and watching the specific redirects (switch of "clear logs").

Comment: i have three type 'admin', 'super' and 'user'

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right, but I think we need to clear all logic errors before we can further investigate the real cause. Otherwise it is really hard (at least for me) to get the problem.

Comment: and localhost also working fine 7.2 but only live problem login issue

Comment: @Pankaj Are you using the same credentials to log in on localhost AND on the live system?

Comment: session.php only attach header.php than working header related page

Comment: yes sir  ? same workin localhost fine php ver. ios not issue

Comment: i want to share this login url ? live

Comment: php 5.6 if you depend

Comment: I can't simply edit your code because I don't know what you want to achieve with your `session.php` code. Currently, you are forwarding every non-admin user back to the login screen. What is your logic behind it? Should only non-logged in users be forwarded to the login screen (as I would suggest)?

Comment: if username and password is correct than login successful otherwise login error massage show.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly stated in his comment on your initial question you whole code needs some refurbishment. I would suggest writing it from scratch to make sure that no SQL injections are possible, at least in this extent. You could, for example, use this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) as a starting point and extent it by your `login_type`. In case you have issues getting your refurbished script to run you can reach out to us again. This is a fair deal I suggest.

Comment: can you share this link

Comment: The link is behind the "tutorial" text above, but here again: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php